# Preapare AM chart based on json nested data

Tags: html, json, amcharts

I need to prepare a simple pie Chart from data coming in json format (that too nested data). How do I begin with?
I want to use `AMcharts`.

Comment: Are you looking to implement a drill-down pie chart? Like this one? http://www.amcharts.com/tips/drill-down-pie-chart/

Comment: Basically you have to manipulate your JSON to AMchart's format. You can use libraries like [lodash](https://lodash.com/) to assist you.